# batch file to add a column in a file from another file with first field matching

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, array-merge

I have two files:

HR.txt

```
12345,Fred,Jones,Sales
12346,Sam,Smith,Sales
12347,Jane,Doe,Purchasing
```

and

JCode.txt

```
12345,July
12346,May
12347,June
```

And I'm trying to create the file Output.txt

```
12345,Fred,Jones,Sales,July
12346,Sam,Smith,Sales,May
12347,Jane,Doe,Purchasing,June
```

I have tried several different findstr combinations, in batch files calling batchfiles, but cannot get the output file to work.  My main batch calls a secondary batch, sending the jcode.txt file as parameters %1 %2, but I cannot seem to add them to the end of the appropriate lines.

Here is what I have currently, after I could not get piping to work using findstr

```
@Echo off&Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

SET _test=%1
set _test


( for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%A in (hr.txt) do (

IF "%_test%"==%%A
 echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%_test%

  ) Else 
   echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D
  )
 )
) >newfile3.csv
```

I realize this would be easier in another language, but I'm limited to data manipulation via batch files.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try using nested for loops with both files (i.e. `for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%A in (hr.txt) do (for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%I in (Jcode.txt) do (...))`

Comment: What's the intention behind `%1`? Based on your three text files you don't need it (also you don't need the `if`)

Comment: Is the first column in your input text files exactly the same? Anyway, you do not need to use `tokens1-5` (there are only 4 anyway), as `tokens=1,*` was enough…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your two input files and your desired output file, there is no need for a parameter `%1` or an `if` at all. Instead, you need to get the second token from the correct line of the second file with a `for /f` and a filter for the correct line (`find "%%A"`)

```
@Echo off&Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%A in (hr.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%Z in ('find "%%A" jcode.txt') do (
    echo %%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%Z
  )
))>newfile3.csv
```

There is no need for delayed expansion (when you don't need it in other parts of your script)

Answer (score 0):

For the task as hand I see the following options:

1. Your sample data for the input files `HR.txt` and `JCode.txt` show that the first column is exactly the same values in the same order, so they could be read simultaneously and the lines could be consolidated by their position, like this:

   ```cmd
   @echo off
   setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

   rem // Define constants here:
   set "_IN1FILE=HR.txt"    & rem // (1st input file)
   set "_IN2FILE=JCode.txt" & rem // (2nd input file)

   rem // Determine least number of available lines:
   for /F %%C in ('^< "%_IN1FILE%" find /C /V ""') do set "CNT=%%C"
   for /F %%C in ('^< "%_IN2FILE%" find /C /V ""') do (
       if %%C lss %CNT% set "CNT=%%C"
   )

   rem // Read both input files simultaneously:
   9< "%_IN1FILE%" 8< "%_IN2FILE%" (
       setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
       rem // Loop through the least number of available lines:
       for /L %%I in (1,1,%CNT%) do (
           rem // Read a line from the 1st input file:
           <&9 (set "LINE1=" & set /P LINE1="")
           rem // Read a line from the 2nd input file:
           <&8 (set "LINE2=" & set /P LINE2="")
           rem /* Build and return an output line consisting of a line of the 1st input file
           rem    and a line of the 2nd input file with the first field value removed: */
           if defined LINE1 if defined LINE2 echo(!LINE1!!LINE2:*,=,!
       )
       endlocal
   )

   endlocal
   exit /B
   ```

   Caveats:

   - first columns of the input files must exactly contain the same data in the same order;
   - lines must be shorter than about 1K bytes/characters;
   - number of lines of both files must be equal;
2. If the data in the first columns of the input files may be in different orders or there are different numbers of items, two nested loops could be used, like this:

   ```cmd
   @echo off
   setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

   rem // Define constants here:
   set "_IN1FILE=HR.txt"    & rem // (1st input file)
   set "_IN2FILE=JCode.txt" & rem // (2nd input file)

   rem // Loop through lines of 1st input file and split at first `,`:
   for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=, eol=," %%I in ("%_IN1FILE%") do (
       rem // Loop through lines of 2nd input file and split at first `,`:
       for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=, eol=," %%K in ("%_IN2FILE%") do (
           rem /* Check first field values of the currently iterated lines of both input
           rem    files against equality and in case build and return an output line: */
           if "%%I"=="%%K" echo(%%I,%%J,%%L
       )
   )

   endlocal
   exit /B
   ```

   Caveats:

   - lines must be shorter than about 8K bytes/characters;
   - first and second column values of both input files must not be empty;
3. As an alternative for the situation with different data in the first columns, the [`findstr` command](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) could be used to get the matching line per line from the other file, like this:

   ```cmd
   @echo off
   setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

   rem // Define constants here:
   set "_IN1FILE=HR.txt"    & rem // (1st input file)
   set "_IN2FILE=JCode.txt" & rem // (2nd input file)

   rem // Loop through lines of 1st input file and split at first `,`:
   for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=, eol=," %%I in ("%_IN1FILE%") do (
       rem /* Search the line in the 2nd input file that begins with the first field
       rem    value of the 1st input file and capture it: */
       for /F "tokens=1* delims=, eol=," %%K in ('
           findstr /B /C:"%%I," "%_IN2FILE%"
       ') do (
           rem // Build and return an output line:
           echo(%%I,%%J,%%L
       )
   )

   endlocal
   exit /B
   ```

   Caveats:

   - lines must be shorter than about 8K bytes/characters;
   - first and second column values of both input files must not be empty;
   - `\` in first column values of `JCodes.txt` may cause unexpected output, because `findstr` uses that character for escaping some meta-characters (even in literal search mode!);

To write the output data to a file use output [redirection `>`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) (for all of the above scripts):

```cmd
consolidate.bat > "consolidated.txt"
```